# GoogleMaps in Api level 8

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

```
LinearLayout maplayout = new LinearLayout(this);
maplayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,600);
MapView mapView = new MapView(this,mapkey);
MapController mc = mapView.getController();
mc.setZoom(20);
maplayout.addView(mapView,params);
setContentView(maplayout);
```

I got a mapview with a specified location by using the above code and its run successfully but

When i swipe in map it doesnt move.. its APK level 8 project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your mapview in xml,

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Or, Add this in your Java file,

```
mapView.setClickable(true);
```